# How to disable current and future dates using pickaday directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular2-directives

I am using "pickaday" directive in AngularJS.

My requirement is to disable current and future dates so that the user is not able to select them. I have applied error on selecting future dates but not able to disable them.

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Related: [How to disable the future dates in datepicker using angularjs and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42852160/3345375)

Answer (score 1):

Use maxDate to limit the selected date.

```
var options = $.extend(true, $scope.global.rangePickeOptions, {
                        startDate: moment(serverTime).startOf('day'),
                        endDate: moment(serverTime),
                        minDate:moment(serverTime).subtract(Number(data)-1, 'days'),
                        maxDate: moment(serverTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        opens: "right"
                    })
```